# In Netty 4, how do I catch all handlers' unprocessed exceptionCaught?

Tags: netty

In my channel pipeline, there are many handlers.

As I understand, if I don't override their `exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause)` method, the default behavior is the `cause` will be thrown out to the pipeline, and something like this will be logged at WARN level by the pipeline:

```
An exception was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception: ...
```

I want to override the above pipeline behavior to add some specific logic (ex: if the `cause` is `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer`, do not log anything to avoid too many "not very useful" log at WARN level).

What should I do?

After some investigation, I found this source code:
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java

```
private void invokeExceptionCaught(final Throwable cause) {
    try {
        handler.exceptionCaught(this, cause);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
            logger.warn(
                    "An exception was thrown by a user handler's " +
                    "exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:", cause);
        }
    }
}
```

Because it's `private`, I don't think I can easily override it without using reflection. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this by define a `ExceptionHandler` then put this handler at the tail of pipeline.

```
ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
p.addLast("business", new SomeBusinessHandler());
p.addLast...
p.addLast("exception", new ExceptionHandler());//Make sure this is the last line when init the pipeline.
```

And code your specific logic within the `exceptionCaught` method. But never rethrow the exception because this is the end of pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why your exceptionCaught method would throw an exception... I think you just want to override the ChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(..) method and handle it there.

Comment: I can catch the exception when overriding `exceptionCaught` of all inbound handlers. But because I'm writing web framework, framework users can pass in user-created handlers (which don't do the overriding) to the framework, I want catch all exceptions even when the handlers do not override `exceptionCaught`.

Comment: Just make sure you always have the last ChannelInboundHandler in the ChannelPipeline which overrides exceptionCaught(...)